# How to optimizing query for multiple joins with subquery for report in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I've defined following tables in my application to fetch the report for every district according to the training date.

```
wi_individual_g(ind_id, ind_district_id, ...)
wi_individual_p(ind_id,prg_id, ind_dalit (yes/no), ind_madhesi (yes/no), ...)
wi_training(trn_id, trn_start_date, trn_ben_type, ...)
wi_indv_training(trn_id, ind_id)
wi_district(dst_id,dst_name)
```

**My problem:** The report has to be generated to count individuals district-wise who are associated with the training between the given **trn_start_date**. The application has predefined date range with the quarters as defined below:

```
$quarter=array('y1q3'=>array('2013-02-01','2013-03-31'),'y1q4'=>array('2013-04-01','2013-06-30')
,'y2q1'=>array('2013-07-01','2013-09-30'),'y2q2'=>array('2013-10-01','2013-012-31'),'y2q3'=>array('2014-01-01','2014-03-31'),'y2q4'=>array('2014-04-01','2014-06-30')
,'y3q1'=>array('2014-07-01','2014-09-30'),'y3q2'=>array('2014-10-01','2014-012-31'),'y3q3'=>array('2015-01-01','2015-03-31'),'y3q4'=>array('2015-04-01','2015-06-30')
,'y4q1'=>array('2015-07-01','2015-09-30'),'y4q2'=>array('2015-10-01','2015-012-31'),'y4q3'=>array('2016-01-01','2016-03-31'),'y4q4'=>array('2016-04-01','2016-06-30')
,'y5q1'=>array('2016-07-01','2016-09-30'),'y5q2'=>array('2016-10-01','2016-012-31'),'y5q3'=>array('2017-01-01','2017-03-31'),'y5q4'=>array('2017-04-01','2017-06-30')
,'y6q1'=>array('2017-07-01','2017-09-30'),'y6q2'=>array('2017-10-01','2017-012-31'),'y6q3'=>array('2018-01-01','2018-03-31'),'y6q4'=>array('2018-04-01','2018-06-30'));
```

If the **trn_start_date** is choosen as Y4Q4 then, the query must count individuals district-wise for each date range as: Y1(Q1-Q4), Y2(Q2-Q4), Y3(Q1-Q4), Y4(Q1-Q4) separately with single query as:

```
Y1  Y2    Y3    Y4  Y5  Y6
8   3948  3511  0   0   0
```

AS a solution, I applied following query:

```
SELECT wi_district.dst_name, 
COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN wi_training.trn_start_date BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2018-06-30' AND 
ind_dalit='yes' THEN wi_individual_g.ind_id END)) AS y6 , 
COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN wi_training.trn_start_date BETWEEN '2016-07-01' AND '2017-06-30' AND     ind_dalit='yes' THEN wi_individual_g.ind_id END)) AS y5 , 
COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN wi_training.trn_start_date BETWEEN '2015-07-01' AND '2016-06-30' AND ind_dalit='yes' THEN wi_individual_g.ind_id END)) AS y4 , 
COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN wi_training.trn_start_date BETWEEN '2014-07-01' AND '2015-06-30' AND ind_dalit='yes' THEN wi_individual_g.ind_id END)) AS y3 , 
COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN wi_training.trn_start_date BETWEEN '2013-07-01' AND '2014-06-30' AND ind_dalit='yes' THEN wi_individual_g.ind_id END)) AS y2 , 
COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN wi_training.trn_start_date BETWEEN '2013-02-01' AND '2013-06-30' AND ind_dalit='yes' THEN wi_individual_g.ind_id END)) AS y1 
FROM wi_individual_g 
INNER JOIN wi_individual_p ON wi_individual_p.ind_id=wi_individual_g.ind_id AND wi_individual_g.ind_is_recepient='yes' 
INNER JOIN wi_district ON wi_district.dst_id=wi_individual_g.ind_district_id AND wi_individual_g.ind_deleted=0 
INNER JOIN wi_indv_training ON wi_indv_training.ind_id=wi_individual_g.ind_id AND wi_indv_training.is_deleted=0 
INNER JOIN wi_training ON wi_training.trn_id=wi_indv_training.trn_id AND wi_training.trn_deleted=0 AND wi_training.trn_beneficiary_type=2 AND wi_training.trn_start_date <='2018-06-30' 
GROUP BY wi_district.dst_name
```

But this query takes more than 5 minutes to execute and that's worst. I also applied the index on fields but achieved somewhat same result.
I would be thankful if someone provide me the best solution.

Comment: `count(distinct)` can take a long time.  Start removing those clauses and see if they are the problem.  That will give you a direction for fixing the problem.

Comment: I've to count unique individuals. So If I remove distinct then the count would get increased for same individuals who are involved in different training. By the way, removing distinct also didn't work.

Comment: in which table is the "ind_dalit".  You have no table/alias reference and without table structures is ambiguous.

Comment: ind_dalit is in wi_individual_p table and it's not in any other tables so the table structures is not ambiguous.

Comment: @SujitBaniya, sorry, missed it, just wasn't sure if your tables were abbreviated or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the way to increase the performance by 3-times:

```
At first : the query took around 128 secs
After suggestion: the query took around 78 secs
Further modification: the query took around 23 secs
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT d.dst_name,
COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN a.trn_start_date BETWEEN '2014-07-01' AND '2015-06-30' THEN a.ind_id END)) AS y3 , 
COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN a.trn_start_date BETWEEN '2013-07-01' AND '2014-06-30' THEN a.ind_id END)) AS y2 , 
COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN a.trn_start_date BETWEEN '2013-02-01' AND '2013-06-30' THEN a.ind_id END)) AS y1  
FROM 
(
    SELECT g.ind_district_id,g.ind_id,t.trn_start_date,t.trn_beneficiary_type
    FROM wi_individual_g g
    INNER JOIN wi_indv_training wit ON g.ind_id = wit.ind_id AND wit.is_deleted = 0 AND g.ind_deleted=0 AND g.ind_is_recepient='yes'
    INNER JOIN wi_training t ON wit.trn_id = t.trn_id AND t.trn_beneficiary_type=2 AND t.trn_deleted = 0
) a
INNER JOIN wi_individual_p p ON p.ind_id=a.ind_id
INNER JOIN wi_district d ON d.dst_id=a.ind_district_id
WHERE p.ind_dalit='yes'
GROUP BY d.dst_name;
```

As a whole, the performance has been increased by 6-times from my previous query. Thank you for the suggestion @DRapp

If anyone having best solution to increase the performance, I would like to thank him!

Answer (score 0):

I have slightly altered the query to put adjust the criteria to the respective
join, or into the WHERE clause where applicable.  I also moved the "ind_dalit=yes"
component to the JOIN to the wi_individual_p table vs in each case statement.

With this, I can better see criteria to offer suggestions of indexes including

```
table              index
wi_individual_g    ( ind_is_recipient, ind_deleted, ind_id, ind_district_id )
wi_individual_p    ( ind_id, ind_dalit )
wi_district        ( dst_id, dst_name )
wi_indv_training   ( ind_id, is_deleted )
wi_training        ( trn_beneficiary_type, trn_deleted, trn_start_date, trn_id )

SELECT 
      d.dst_name, 
      COUNT( DISTINCT( CASE WHEN t.trn_start_date 
         BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2018-06-30' 
         THEN g.ind_id END)) AS y6,
      COUNT( DISTINCT( CASE WHEN t.trn_start_date 
         BETWEEN '2016-07-01' AND '2017-06-30' 
         THEN g.ind_id END)) AS y5,
      COUNT( DISTINCT( CASE WHEN t.trn_start_date 
         BETWEEN '2015-07-01' AND '2016-06-30' 
         THEN g.ind_id END)) AS y4, 
      COUNT( DISTINCT( CASE WHEN t.trn_start_date 
         BETWEEN '2014-07-01' AND '2015-06-30' 
         THEN g.ind_id END)) AS y3, 
      COUNT( DISTINCT( CASE WHEN t.trn_start_date 
         BETWEEN '2013-07-01' AND '2014-06-30' 
         THEN g.ind_id END)) AS y2, 
      COUNT( DISTINCT( CASE WHEN t.trn_start_date 
         BETWEEN '2013-02-01' AND '2013-06-30' 
         THEN g.ind_id END)) AS y1 
   FROM 
      wi_individual_g g
         INNER JOIN wi_individual_p p
            ON g.ind_id = p.ind_id
            AND p.ind_dalit='yes' 
         INNER JOIN wi_district d
            ON g.ind_district_id = d.dst_id 
         INNER JOIN wi_indv_training wit 
            ON g.ind_id = wit.ind_id
            AND wit.is_deleted = 0 
         INNER JOIN wi_training t
            ON wit.trn_id = t.trn_id 
            AND t.trn_beneficiary_type = 2 
            AND t.trn_deleted = 0 
            AND t.trn_start_date >= '2013-02-01'
            AND t.trn_start_date <= '2018-06-30' 
   WHERE
          g.ind_is_recepient = 'yes' 
      AND g.ind_deleted = 0
   GROUP BY 
      d.dst_name
```

Here is another option you might try.  This pre-queries (alias PQ) distinct "g" district and ind_id per date group 1-6 vs returning every dated record.  Then the result is a simple sum per district.

```
SELECT 
      d.dst_name, 
      SUM( PQ.DateGrp = 6 ) AS y6,
      SUM( PQ.DateGrp = 5 ) AS y5,
      SUM( PQ.DateGrp = 4 ) AS y4,
      SUM( PQ.DateGrp = 3 ) AS y3,
      SUM( PQ.DateGrp = 2 ) AS y2,
      SUM( PQ.DateGrp = 1 ) AS y1
   FROM 
      ( select distinct 
              g.ind_district_id, 
              g.ind_id,
              CASE WHEN t.trn_start_date BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2018-06-30' THEN 6 
                   WHEN t.trn_start_date BETWEEN '2016-07-01' AND '2017-06-30' THEN 5
                   WHEN t.trn_start_date BETWEEN '2015-07-01' AND '2016-06-30' THEN 4
                   WHEN t.trn_start_date BETWEEN '2014-07-01' AND '2015-06-30' THEN 3
                   WHEN t.trn_start_date BETWEEN '2013-07-01' AND '2014-06-30' THEN 2
                   WHEN t.trn_start_date BETWEEN '2013-02-01' AND '2013-06-30' THEN 1
                   ELSE 0 END DateGrp 
           from
              wi_training t
                 JOIN wi_indv_training wit 
                    ON t.trn_id = wit.trn_id 
                   AND wit.is_deleted = 0 
                   JOIN wi_individual_g g
                          g.ind_is_recepient = 'yes' 
                      AND g.ind_deleted = 0
                      AND wit.ind_id = g.ind_id 
                      INNER JOIN wi_individual_p p
                         ON g.ind_id = p.ind_id
                        AND p.ind_dalit='yes' 
           where
                  t.trn_beneficiary_type = 2 
              AND t.trn_deleted = 0 
              AND t.trn_start_date >= '2013-02-01'
              AND t.trn_start_date <= '2018-06-30' ) PQ
         INNER JOIN wi_district d
            ON PQ.ind_district_id = d.dst_id 
      GROUP BY 
         d.dst_name
```

Comment: I used the query you've provided and also applied some missing index on table. But it's still taking 78 secs to execute. I would like to know If I've done any mistake in applying query. How other enterprise applications apply complex query to obtain results in least time?

Comment: thank you for your effort. I've tried the suggestion you provided its taking around 79 secs